# Reset date in datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

Using bootstrap [datetimepicker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). Submitting the form via ajax and need to reset date based on ajax response. But currently facing an issue to reset the date selection from JQuery. Here is the code I used to reset:

```
$("#date_from").datetimepicker("setDate", null);
```

Comment: Which version you are using??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this.

```
$('#date_from').val("");
$('#date_from').datetimepicker('update');
```

Refered  from methods tab of [datepicker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#methods)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
    $('#date_from').data("DateTimePicker").clear();
```

reference here:
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#clear

Answer (score 1):

@Jayaraj.K's answer did not work for me.
This is what I used:

```
$('#date_from').data('DateTimePicker').date(null)
$('#date_from').datetimepicker('update');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#date_from").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: Could you add some details regarding your code and it how addresses the problem(s) in the question? Code only answers are not very useful, especially for future readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks,

Comment: @Cristik I have included the link on the question. It is already resolved by the first answer.

Comment: Using datetimepicker not datepicker. Please see the link on the question and first answer did the work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
$.datepicker._clearDate(this);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. datepicker is wrong as I am using datetimepicker